# How do you move the play again button to under the box?

Tags: html, css

How do I make sure my play again button moves up to the top so that it sits perfectly under the black border box?

The black border box has a class name called `.foot`

```css
.button {
  background: rgb(247, 150, 192);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(247, 150, 192, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 174, 241, 1) 100%);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), -4px -4px 5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.foot {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 450px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="foot"></footer>
<button class="button">Play Again</button>
```

Comment: ` .foot {

    border-style:solid ;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 300px; 
    margin-bottom: 450px;
    height: 100px;
   
    

} ` 

this is the border box i am referring about.

I am not sure how to move up my "Play Again" button just beneath it

Comment: Can you also update the html please ?

Comment: @zaidzac I've turned your code into a snippet, please add the element with the class `foot` in the format/position you want it, so we can see the problem.

Comment: @DBS okay i am done editing it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin-bottom of the foot

```css
.button {
  background: rgb(247, 150, 192);
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(247, 150, 192, 1) 0%, rgba(118, 174, 241, 1) 100%);
  transition: transform 250ms;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -1px -1px 20px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), -4px -4px 5px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 7px 7px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4), 4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.foot {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="foot"></footer>
<button class="button">Play Again</button>
```